# Structuring data frames to list R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

here is some data and end result I'm hoping. I have number of dfs (example with 2) and I want to structure them as list. Example explains it better:

```
names <- as.yearmon(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), to=as.Date("2010-05-01"), by="month"))
names

df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), X2 = c(1,2,3,4,5), X3 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
rownames(df1) <- names
df2 <- data.frame(Y1 = c(10,20,30,40,50), Y2 = c(10,20,30,40,50), Y3 = c(10,20,30,40,50))
rownames(df2) <- names

FullList <- list()
length(FullList) <- 5

names(FullList) <- names

FullList[[1]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[1], rownames(df1)), ]
FullList[[1]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[1], rownames(df2)), ]

FullList[[2]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[2], rownames(df1)), ]
FullList[[2]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[2], rownames(df2)), ]

FullList[[3]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[3], rownames(df1)), ]
FullList[[3]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[3], rownames(df2)), ]

FullList[[4]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[4], rownames(df1)), ]
FullList[[4]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[4], rownames(df2)), ]

FullList[[5]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[5], rownames(df1)), ]
FullList[[5]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[5], rownames(df2)), ]
```

So from 2 or more data frames end up with list of list, with common name as main list name. End result should look like `FullList`, what is best method achieving this?

Comment: Dataframes _are_ lists. Perhaps you just want `unclass`? At the moment you have lists with elements that are still dataframes. Was that what you wanted?

Comment: Ignoring the terribleness of the data structure you want, here is a trivial way of achieving that format: `FullList = mapply(function(x, y) list(x, y), split(df1, rownames(df1)), split(df2, rownames(df2)), SIMPLIFY = F)` This replaces all code at and below the line `FullList <- list()`

Comment: Thanks for comments, maybe I have to reconsider my structure. I have alot of diffenrent things, which are all ordered by date, thought that having a list with a date on first would keep things organized. These dfs could matrix or vector or something else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve the request, but I do agree with Vlo this appears to be an unwieldily data-structure:

```
lapply( names, function(nm) {
        list( df1[ nm == rownames(df1), ,drop=FALSE], 
              df2[ nm == rownames(df2), ,drop=FALSE]) ) }
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple loop can work for you.

```
for (listrow in 1:5) {
  for (dataframe in 1:2) {
eval(parse(text=paste("FullList[[",listrow,"]][[",dataframe,"]] <- df",dataframe,"[match(names(FullList)[",listrow,"], rownames(df",dataframe,")), ]",sep="")))
}
}
```

This loop executes following commands

```
for (listrow in 1:5) {
  for (dataframe in 1:2) {
    print(paste("FullList[[",listrow,"]][[",dataframe,"]] <- df",dataframe,"[match(names(FullList)[",listrow,"], rownames(df",dataframe,")), ]",sep=""))
  }
}
[1] "FullList[[1]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[1], rownames(df1)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[1]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[1], rownames(df2)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[2]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[2], rownames(df1)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[2]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[2], rownames(df2)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[3]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[3], rownames(df1)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[3]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[3], rownames(df2)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[4]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[4], rownames(df1)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[4]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[4], rownames(df2)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[5]][[1]] <- df1[match(names(FullList)[5], rownames(df1)), ]"
[1] "FullList[[5]][[2]] <- df2[match(names(FullList)[5], rownames(df2)), ]"
```